Expected test reliability for short, multiple-choice tests?
How might I calculate the expected test reliability (internal, e.g., KR-20) for tests of various lengths?  What assumptions would underlie such calculations? Are there existing tables or calculators available or do I need to do this myself?
For example, if I have a multiple-choice test consisting of 10 4-choice questions and the average inter-item correlation is .20, with 100 test takers, what level of test reliability should I expect?

You shouldn't be able to expect any reliability a priori unless you already have data from past studies which would indicate that. The reliability will be dependent on:

The strength of the relationships between items and the construct you are measuring will greatly determine how many items you need. For example, if you fit a one-factor CFA with just three items, but their factor loadings are around $\lambda = .95$, then the reliability should be pretty good.
The tau equivalence between items will also play a role. This means how equally each relates to a construct like anxiety, depression, etc. If all of your items equally contribute to the construct, then reliability should be better than items which are all over the place. Note that measures like Cronbach's alpha rely on tau equivalence to be accurate, whereas others (e.g. McDonald's omega) do not.
Typically more items will stabilize and at times increase reliability, particularly alpha and K-20 scores.
The more error in each item's measurement, the more this contributes to poor reliability.
The wording of items can also influence this (e.g. double negatives cause poor reliability).
Items which allow guessing tend to be less reliable.
The number of subjects measured on each item will largely stabilize the estimates of reliability. If say we have only three people observed across three items, we have substantially less estimable variance than say 1000 people across the same three items.

There are probably some other influences I am forgetting at the moment, but you can see that a simple guess of how your reliability should look is determined by several factors which you may not always be able to control.
Having said that, you can certainly simulate what you want to see what you should expect. Since you seem to have some parameters already:

For example, if I have a multiple-choice test consisting of 10 4-choice questions and the average inter-item correlation is .20, with 100 test takers, what level of test reliability should I expect?

One could simulate what you want and see how it looks. Here I use R to simulate, which has some nifty convenience functions for estimating latent variable models in lavaan. I just use three items for both models below for simplicity, with some made-up settings for the items.
#### Load Library ####
library(lavaan)
library(semTools)

#### Specify Model ####
population.model.1 <- ' 

# Single factor model with three items
f =~ .9*x1 + 0.1*x2 + 1.2*x3

# Specify item variance
x1 ~~ .4*x1 
x2 ~~ .2*x2
x3 ~~ .3*x3

' 

#### Create Data ####
set.seed(123) # set seed to reproduce results

data.1 <- simulateData(
  population.model.1, # model
  sample.nobs=100 # number of observations
  )

head(data.1) # check look of data
nrow(data.1) # check obs.

#### Fitted Values of Model ####
fit.1 <- sem(population.model.1, data = data.1)
summary(fit.1)

#### Check Reliability ####
compRelSEM(fit.1)

#### Run More Reliable Items ####
population.model.2 <- ' 

# Single factor model with three items
f =~ 2*x1 + 2*x2 + 2*x3

# Specify item variance
x1 ~~ .1*x1 
x2 ~~ .1*x2
x3 ~~ .1*x3

' 

data.2 <- simulateData(
  population.model.2, # model
  sample.nobs=100 # number of observations
)

fit.2 <- sem(population.model.2, data = data.2)
summary(fit.2)

#### Check Reliability Again ####
compRelSEM(fit.2)

The first part simulates data based off unequal factor loadings and flippant item variances. The reliability, reliably, isn't perfect. The second part simulates an alternative model with equal factor loadings and tiny error variances, which produce a much more reliable composite. Each is estimated with 100 people.

By flippant item variances do you mean arbitrary?  (I would think item variances could be estimated based on the difficulty level.)

You can simulate either. One being due to systematic effects on difficulty (such as a four item test where 90 percent of responses are correct and thus give little variance) or just random variation attrituable to whatever you want, either known or unknown.
